# Error when trying to fetch data from a database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>   Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT `id`, `name`, `icon` ORDER BY `id` ASC
>     Filename: D:/wamp/www/codeIgniter_latest_3_dev/system/database/DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 691

Comment: The error is pretty self explanitory `Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'`. Your trying to select and order by a field that does not exist

Comment: Also you arent even selecting from any table

Comment: Can you post the code where you are generating this query

Answer (score 0):

You have to SELECT columns FROM a table. You are missing the table name so the DBMS does not know about any column names

The syntax should be

```
SELECT id, name, icon FROM aTableName ORDER BY id ASC
----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You have to use a real table name from your database

Comment: Hey, how come this isn't "green"? Or is it because it wasn't "eco-friendly" enough? haha!

Comment: New users! Had one question go green 6 months after I answered it recently